# Calling unknown method: yii\web\User::getModel()

Tags: yii2, users

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста.. Мне нужно создать обращение к авторизованному пользователю.

В index.php я прописала:

```
<div class="photocaption">
    <h4>Здравствуйте, <?php echo Yii::$app->user->getModel()->name; ?>!</h4>
</div>
```

Но вылетает ошибка:

```
Calling unknown method: yii\web\User::getModel()
```

Как правильно нужно создать обращение к пользователю?

Comment: Добрый вечер. Авторизован пользователь?

Comment: @slo_nik Добрый вечер, да авторизован..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К авторизованному пользователю можно обратиться несколькими способами.

```
$user = Yii::$app->user->getIdentity();
echo $user->login; // подставьте вместо логин своё название из таблицы пользователей

// or
echo Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
```

Так же можно создать публичный метод, в котором по $id получать нужного пользователя. Полезно использовать в crud.

Ну а ошибка говорит о том, что Вы обращаетесь к несуществующему методу в модели. В таком случае полезно заглядывать в документацию и использовать редактор с автоподстановкой. Например PhpStorm.